# Set update form checkbox array to 0 instead of NULL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I have a update form that populates from a database dynamically, I have two checkboxes in my form that post to an array so I can hit one submit button and update all rows with a foreach statement.  The text fields work as they should, but when the checkbox fields post to their array, they leave out the zeros my arrays become shorter.

How do I add 0 where a null checkbox would be?

this is my form

```
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">

<input type="hidden" name="ss_id[]" value="<?php echo $row_rsSnapshot['ss_id']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="ss_yearmonth[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_rsSnapshot['ss_yearmonth'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" />
<tr>
  <td>
  <input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rsSnapshot['ss_inventory'],1))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox"  name="ss_inventory[]" value=""  <?php if (!(strcmp(htmlentities($row_rsSnapshot['ss_inventory'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'),""))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> />

  </td>
  <td>

  <input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rsSnapshot['ss_write_off'],1))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox"  name="ss_write_off[]" value=""  <?php if (!(strcmp(htmlentities($row_rsSnapshot['ss_write_off'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'),""))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?>

  </td>
  <td> 
  <input type="text" name="ss_date[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_rsSnapshot['ss_date'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="text" name="ss_transaction[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_rsSnapshot['ss_transaction'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); ?>" size="32" />
  </td>...
```

And here is my sql update query

```
    foreach($_POST['ss_id'] as $key=>$ss_id){


    $ss_inventory = GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['ss_inventory'][$key]) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0");
    $ss_write_off = GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['ss_write_off'][$key]) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0");
    $ss_date = $_POST['ss_date'][$key];
    $ss_transaction = $_POST['ss_transaction'][$key];
    $ss_debit = $_POST['ss_debit'][$key];
    $ss_credit = $_POST['ss_credit'][$key];
    $ss_yearmonth = $_POST['ss_yearmonth'][$key];



$sql = "UPDATE snapshot SET ss_inventory = '$ss_inventory', ss_write_off = '$ss_write_off', ss_date = '$ss_date', ss_transaction = '$ss_transaction', ss_debit = '$ss_debit', ss_credit = '$ss_credit' , ss_yearmonth = '$ss_yearmonth' WHERE ss_id = '$ss_id' ";

 mysql_select_db($database_connMyayla, $connMyayla);
 $Result1 = mysql_query($sql, $connMyayla) or die(mysql_error());

}

  }
 mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser does not submit unchecked checkboxes. You'll need to either give unique names, or simply use radio buttons.

Comment: using unique names will not work because the number of rows always change.

Comment: Assuming you're generating the form with php (which you are), it's trivial to include some sort of counter or the actual id in the checkbox name. Like I said, you could also use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: I see what you mean now.. I posted an answer, but I'm giving you a check for setting me straight!! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this solved it

If anyone is interested...

I put a counter to find out how many rows are being populated with this query and inserted that into my checkbox name array...

```
$i = 0;

 do { 

...

      <td>
      <input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rsSnapshot['ss_inventory'],1))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox"  name="ss_inventory[<?php echo $i;?>]" value=""  <?php if (in_array($i, $ss_inventory)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />
      </td>

      <td>
       <input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_rsSnapshot['ss_write_off'],1))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox"  name="ss_write_off[<?php echo $i;?>]" value=""  <?php if (in_array($i, $ss_write_off)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />
      </td>


....    
$i++;

    } while ($row_rsSnapshot = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSnapshot));
```

now the checkboxes that are checked will correspond with the correct array number..

e.g.

lets say you have 4 rows of data,  but you only check the checkboxes for row 2 and 4.

```
//run this to see your result

print_r($_POST['ss_inventory']);

//outputs:  Array ([1] => [3] =>)
```

Before this was my output, everything was pushed up to the start of my array because the false checkboxes were not being submitted or NULL. so rows 1 and 2 would result true.

```
//outputs:  Array ([0] => [1] =>)
```

Also See 
[Checkbox "checked"-value jumps up to earlier array values, when array is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438958/checkbox-checked-value-jumps-up-to-earlier-array-values-when-array-is-empty)